# Facebook login problematic

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have registered at Facebook Developer site with credentials xyz@gmail.com, however if I am logged into the Facebook app on my device with this account (Developer account) it works fine, just when I change the Facebook log in to say abc@gmail.com it does not. What might be the problem? Or will it work this way till I add a application signature key that is the final production key?

I spent around 12 hours yesterday trying to figure this out.

So Far:

I am following  atutorial [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

I wrote this tutorial and added up on top of it with adifferent email ID and credentials, that works fine.

However I have a different email now ( My organizations) and I am trying to follow same and implement it one of my projects. Its not working. Here is my calss file:

```
public class FacebookMain extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebook);


         // start Facebook Login
          Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                          // callback after Graph API response with user object
                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                              TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                              welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                            }
                          }
                        }).executeAsync();
                }
            }
          });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

This is my Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<supports-screens
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.XXX.XXX.FacebookMain"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.XXX.XXX.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
</application>
```

My Credentials on FB dash:

```
Package Name
com.XXX.XXX
Class Name
com.XXX.XXX.FacebookMain
Key Hashes
0xE8OZLvTPJOrP4/VOZ07e7U8Kw=
```

The textview with ID = welcome does not update, however if I try my old project it works. Whats going on?

I have followed each and every step atleast constructed the project thrice from scratch!

Comment: Nope I am fixed in this. I think they provide login to those accounts to which the signing key is referenced to, unless a production key is specified.

Comment: did you try with final production key?

Comment: My app is not release ready yet, that is what I want to confirm from someone! Facebook documentation sucks!

Comment: if your problem not solve then just try my demo!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Facebook allow only developer and tester you specify on Facebook.com. You have to enable your app for all users. Go to developer.Facebook.com click on app and select your app. Go to status and review in left panel and choose yes to enable it for all user.

Answer (score 1):

This is demo made by me with all function, just try ,this will work  ( just change applicationId in strings.xml)

https://github.com/hardikbhalodi/FBDemo

Comment: Yours is signed by a production key?

Comment: generate key with this way https://github.com/hardikbhalodi/AIO-Demo/blob/master/AllDemoInOne/res/raw/help